# Suggestion for building a small Hadoop cluster for learning purpose

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, cluster-computing, distributed-computing

I have a test for my Big Data class where I have to do some sort of big data analytics with 'smaller' datasets. I actually have my stuff figured it out. I installed Hadoop 2.8.1 and Spark 2.2.0 (I use PySpark to build a program) in standalone mode on my Ubuntu 16.04 from source. I'm actually good to go to do my thing by my own.

The thing is, some of my friends are struggling in configuring all of these and I thought to myself "why don't I make my own little cluster with my classmates". So I'm looking for suggestions.

My laptop has 12 GB RAM and Intel Core i5.

Comment: You could build a shared cluster in AWS, GCP, or Azure...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your friends have trouble setting up spark in standalone mode (meaning no cluster at all, just local computation). I don't think setting up a cluster they can work with takes away from the complexity they will face. Or are they trying to set up a cluster? Because standalone mode of Spark really doesn't need much configuration.

Another approach is to use a preconfigured VM everyone can use individually. Either prepared by yourself, or there are sandboxes by different providers, e.g. [Cloudera](https://www.cloudera.com/downloads/quickstart_vms/5-12.html) and [Hortonworks](https://hortonworks.com/products/sandbox/).

Comment: Yes, correct. Not only that, some of them also have trouble running Cloudera and Hortonworks because of their computational power limitation. Plus, one of the requisite for this test is that we have to do our data analysis in MapReduce environment. Honestly, that's quite vague. But our instructor gave us a recommendation, running Spark at the top of HDFS.

Comment: In that case, if you have a working small cluster (and your laptop should be strong enough to run a node imho), then they can just point their configuration to your IP/Port.

Comment: How can you tell that your laptop is strong enough to run a node? Our biggest dataset has 302k rows in them. Say I have a cluster with 5 nodes, with my 12 GB RAM and i5 processor, do you think it's capable enough?

Comment: @Tata I have used Vagrant to create a 5 node Hadoop cluster with an i5 and 16 GB of RAM... If you use Ambari with its blueprint features, you can easily export your Vagrantfile definition and Ambari blueprint to recreate a cluster on any system.